# How can I have inertia scrolling for my touchpad?

Tags: synaptics

I'd like to have inertia scrolling for my touchpad, how can I do this, thanks!

Comment: Kinetic Scrolling as it's know everywhere else, depends on the touch-pad being able to do it, now the only software i see was using it it's Chrome & Firefox both with their respective extensions.

Comment: Uri, I think you contradict yourself by saying that Kinetic Scrolling is a hardware feature of a touchpad, but then saying that Firefox and Chrome have extensions to implement it.
I am pretty sure this is a software feature which can technically be implemented even for mouse or keyboard input. Software implementations may rely on certain touchpad features, such as multitouch, to, say, distinquish scroll (two fingers) from a click (one finger), but there's nothing in the hardware which is specific to kinetic scrolling I believe.

Comment: Is this the same as "coasting"? If so, synclient can set a couple of options

Comment: Yes, it's the same as coasting in the Synaptics driver. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/338841) on how to configure it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the closest we have in Ubuntu is the '[Natural Scrolling](https://github.com/cemmanouilidis/naturalscrolling)' by Chalarampos. Natural Scrolling allows the direction of scrolling to be toggled.

[image: Natural Scrolling]

Natural Scrolling has the following dependencies: (Click on the link to install)

[couch-db python-desktopcouch-application gawk](http://apt://couchdb,python-desktopcouch-application,gawk)

Then download the .deb file and install it.

[dl.dropbox.com/u/1111373/NaturalScrolling/naturalscrolling_0.2.4_all.deb](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1111373/NaturalScrolling/naturalscrolling_0.2.4_all.deb)

Comment: the hyperlink you provided for `apt` does not work on click. Maybe you should change it to a `apt-get` command.

Comment: This is about reverse scrolling not "inertia" scrolling, or what most of the world calls it: kinetic scrolling.

Answer (score -2):

Well. First you have to know that inertial scrolling is patented by Apple. So it is almost impossible to have the same software installed. Then, as far as I know. The touchpad of an Apple laptop uses another technology than other brand laptops. The Apple touchpad's laptops can identify multitouch.

Comment: It's not like Apple laptops are the only ones with multitouch touchpads.