# Configure '50-synaptics.conf' for kinetic scrolling?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling

My laptop has a Synaptics touchpad with multi-touch support. Kinetic two-finger scrolling works fine on windows, how can I get it to work on ubuntu?

I have already reversed the scrolling direction by editing the `/usr/share/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`, all I need now is to give it some inertia.

I am using the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

This [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/synaptics.4.html) explains a lot about the different parameters, but I can't seem to find the right parameters to set in order to achieve this. Please do not answer unless you have tried this before. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux kinetic scrolling  is called "Coasting", at least in the Synaptics driver.

You can do it by adding  following option lines to the file `50-synaptics.conf` file, adapting the values as you require:

```
# Coasting configuration
Option "CornerCoasting" "0"
Option "CoastingSpeed" "20"
Option "CoastingFriction" "50"
```

Comment: I copied those three lines and it didn't work? I have edge scrolling disabled, I use two finger scrolling. Does this apply to two-finger scrolling too?  (I did a restart to make sure)

Comment: Yes and you also need to add in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d.

Comment: You should have edge scrolling enable.

Comment: When enabling edge scrolling through the GUI I cannot enable both two-finger and edge scrolling. How can I enable it in the configuration file?

Comment: Anyhow what is the syntax for boolean values? "on"/"off", "0"/"1" or "true"/"false"?

Comment: syntax for boolean values is "0"/"1"

Comment: i have no /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder, also some changes in the synaptics.conf file aren't taking effect anymore, does the section they're in matter?

Comment: I finally managed to fix this. I set friction to 10 and speed to 1, and it worked fine. I also disabled edge scrolling and it still works!

Answer (score 4):

Kinetic two-finger scrolling is called "conventional coasting" in the Synaptics driver:

> Coasting comes in two flavors: conventional (finger off) coasting, and corner (finger on) coasting. Conventional coasting is enabled when coasting is enabled, and CornerCoasting is set to false. [[Synaptics manpage](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html)]

The two modes are mutually exclusive: kinetic two-finger scrolling does not work with corner coasting enabled. So let's enable conventional coasting. As per the new Ubuntu recommendations in the file, do not edit your `50-synaptics.conf` directly but create a directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and in it a file like `51-synaptics-tweaks.conf`, containing:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "CornerCoasting" "0"
        Option "CoastingSpeed" "20"
        Option "CoastingFriction" "50"
EndSection
```

To see the effect, restart X.

As you noticed, the speed and friction values are hardware dependent. What works on one touchpad might not have a noticable effect on another. Some experimentation might be needed.

For experiments, it is better to use `synclient`, as it creates an immediate (but non-permanent) effect without having to restart X all the time. The equivalent to the above would be:

```
synclient CornerCoasting=0 CoastingSpeed=20 CoastingFriction=50
```