# Scrollling deceleration like in OSX

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, mouse-scroll, scrolling

Is it possible in Ubuntu with a touchpad 2-finger scrolling? I do not know how to explain this, but the feeling is like kicking with your foot on a skateboard: When you scroll down a long page - if you do a fast 2-finger movement it keeps scrolling down (although decelerating) so you scroll much faster.

Right now in my Ubuntu installation: as soon as your fingers leave the touchpad, the scrolling abruptly stops. OSX Touchpad behaviour is much more natural in this case.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Previous questions: [Touchpad cursor inertia](http://askubuntu.com/q/235630) and [How can I have inertia scrolling for my touchpad?](http://askubuntu.com/q/56528); Hardware solution: ["Hyper-fast" scrolling](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190926/how-can-i-configure-a-logitech-m705-to-use-stepless-scrolling#comment266149_190926)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13.04 "inertia scrolling" is the term that I was missing - thanks ændrük! The solution looks promising. Please post your answer so I can mark it as solved. =)